# Identify encoding to convert between known strings

Tags: rfid

I have some ISO 11785 RFID animal tags which are programmed with a number and also have a number written on them. The two numbers are matched through a text file which was sent with the RFID tags. The problem is that the numbers returned by the RFID reader don't match the numbers in the file. I would like someone to help me determine how the tag numbers have been converted to be put in the file. The RFID tag returns a number with manufacturer code followed by a unique animal code.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
RFID Tag         | RFID Response From Tag
8000F580076C2BA9 | 982 000124529577
8000F580076C2C34 | 982 000124529716
8000F580076C2C32 | 982 000124529714
8000F580076C2DD4 | 982 000124530132
8000F580076C2BDC | 982 000124529628
```

Can anyone suggest what I should do to the number on the left to get to the number on the right? I have tried converting from hex to decimal but that doesn't seem to work.

**Edit**

It turns out if I take the last 7 characters of hex then they become the animal ID, the F58 translates to the 3982 which can be worked around to get me the 982 part. I think I should be able to work from this but thought I would leave the post anyway in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The field encoding is defined by the ISO standard.
bits
    1 Animal flag
  2-4 retag counter
  5-9 user information
10-15 reserved
   16 additional data flag
17-26 country/manufacturer code (982 is Allflex)
27-64 unique ID